# Moving the .cs files generated by a T4 Template

Tags: c#, vb.net, t4

How can I move the .cs or .vb files generated by a T4 template to another folder of the project in visual studio 2010.

Comment: Can you not just use the mouse to drag them into the proper place?  Perhaps I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in order to do that we have to edit the T4 template file. For that in visual studio 2010 there is a extension named [Visual T4](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/40a887aa-f3be-40ec-a85d-37044b239591). So after opening the .T4 or .tt file you can change the path of the folder where you want to generate your code files.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but this project looks like it might do what you want. It allows you to specify a different folder or even another project to generate the files in.

[T4Toolbox](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/03/t4-toolbox-generating-files-in-different-folders-and-projects/)